# how to change cell style use Obect(cell) by mouseEvent in mxGraph?

Tags: javascript, stylesheet, mxgraph

I can change svg style, but page do not work, maybe need redraw().how to do it?

to save cell node

```
let svg = {}
```

click function

```
function clickFn(){
    let keys = Object.keys(svg)
    keys.forEach((item,i)=>{
        if(item.split('.')[0] === 'col' ){
            svg[item].style = 'col'
            if(me.sourceState.cell.id === item){
                svg[item].style = 'active'
                //do not work!is need redraw()?
                //but svg[item] hasn't redraw()
            }else{
                svg[item].style = 'col'
            }
            // svg[item].shape.redraw();
        }
    })
}
```

event listener

```
graph.addMouseListener({
    mouseDown: function(sender, me){
            if(me.sourceState && me.sourceState.cell && me.sourceState.cell.id.split('.')[0] === 'col'){
                clickFn()
            }
        },
    });
```

insert node use 'col + col.sort'  to save

```
let WIDTH1 = 280,WIDTH2 = 250,WIDTH3 = 240,id = '';
this.dataBlood.forEach((fold,i)=>{
    svg['fold' + fold.sort] = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, '', 0, 0, WIDTH1, 0, 'column');
    fold.tables.forEach((table,index)=>{
        id = 'fold' + i + '.table' + index;
        svg[id] = graph.insertVertex(svg['fold' + fold.sort], id, table.name, 0, 0, WIDTH2, 30,'table');
        svg[id].collapsed = true;
        table.col.forEach((col)=>{
            svg['col.' + col.id] = graph.insertVertex(svg[id], 'col.' + col.id, col.name, 0, 0, WIDTH3, 20,'col');
        })
    })

})
```

insert link

```
this.linkBlood.forEach((item=>{
    graph.insertEdge(parent, null,'' , svg['col.' + item.source], svg['col.' + item.target],'line');
}))
```

}

Comment: No idea what you are trying to do, but there are loads of "native" feature in mxGraph so that you don't have to touch the SVG manually. Surprising that you can't find help in the examples? I'd love to help but I really don't understand what you are trying to do. A bit of context would help.